# MKMapView Layout issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i would like to use a Map Kit View has a subview of a TableViewController that occupies only a portion of the screen, like i set in the storyboard

[image: Storyboard Image]

so the idea is that when the user enter in this page, the navigation with map is ready to start but he can also manage with the cells of the tableView. This is the code that i have for the navigation:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.delegate = self

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  40.7142700
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -74.0059700

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "My Position"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

}
```

my problem is that: when i come in this page, the view of the Map it's automatically enlarged by occupying the entire screen and i do not want this, never, i have to do that the view of the map remains always a subview of the tableViewController always keeping the same dimensions, so how i can adjust it? The code below is the entire tableViewController

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var coordinate : (Double , Double)
        var type: String
        var address: String
    }


    var rows = 0

    var users = [User]()

    let CS = User(name: "Sporting Club", images: UIImage(named: "1.png")! , coordinate:(41.844326 , 12.467619), type: "Sport", address: "Via dei Cocchieri, 1A")
    let D = User(name: "94Tele", images: UIImage(named: "5.png")! , coordinate:(41.893992 , 12.488673), type: "Restaurant", address: "Via della Madonna dei Monti, 94")
    let PS = User(name: "Chiostro del Bramante ", images: UIImage(named: "4.png")! , coordinate:(41.899706 , 12.471469), type: "Museum", address: "Arco della Pace, 5")
    let B = User(name: "Teatro Sala Umberto", images: UIImage(named: "2.png")! , coordinate:(41.903085 , 12.481995), type: "Theater", address: "Via della Mercede, 50")
    let EC = User(name: "Mangiarte", images: UIImage(named: "3.png")! , coordinate:(41.896909, 12.512516), type: "Restaurant", address: "Via degli Equi, 16")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.delegate = self

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  41.869909
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 12.512516

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "My Position"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

        users.append(CS)
        users.append(D)
        users.append(PS)
        users.append(B)
        users.append(EC)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        insertRowsMode3()
    }

    func insertRowsMode2() {

        for i in 0..<users.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: users[i])
        }
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:User) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }

    func insertRowsMode3() {
        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }

    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < users.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.15) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

      let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.myImage.image = user.images
        cell.myLabel.text = user.name
        cell.myTypeLabel.text = user.type



        return (cell)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    @IBAction func mapTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  40.7142700
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -74.0059700

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "My House"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options) 
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

        guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

        let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

             if let user = sender as? User {

            guest.local = user.name

             guest.localImage = user.images

            guest.localType = user.type

            guest.localAddress = user.address
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image: code window output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` not a `UITableViewController`. So you can place the mapView on the top of the `UIViewController` and the tableView under it with some constraints. If you want the map to move with the scroll of the table view then add the map in the first cell of the `UITabelView` you have just created.

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit

    class CourseClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        map.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
  Int) -> Int {

          //Change according to need if array of data put array.count
          return 1
      }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        //Change according to need
          return 1
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
  for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell


          return cell
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) {

      }
  }
```

See image:

[image]

Comment: so is impossible to do in a TableViewController ?

Comment: Nop this is the best way to do it. It is very easy. I can update the answer and show you how to add a table view to the viewController by adding the delegate and datasource protocols.

Comment: I edit my question adding the entire code of the TableViewController, as you can see, the problem is that i have some func which need to be in a TableViewController

Comment: @bero i can see the code but i cannot see anything that needs a TableViewController and cannot be added to the ordinary tableView. You have all the delegate functions and everything you need to implement your code in the tableView instead of TableViewController.

Comment: build the new viewController call it CourseClass and add the map and the tableView to it as shown. Add one prototype cell. Then add the code i wrote in the CourseClass.swift then add your additional location code and all the other code that you use in the table functions. And it will work the same as making a UITableViewController.

Comment: i did but there is one issue  come out, i edit my question and post an image at the bottom to show you

Comment: @bero Right click and grab to connect the tableView on the storyboard to the IBOutlet tableView in the CourseClass.swift

Comment: thank you, now it working but crushing for this : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fbf5b0d5600; frame = (0 322; 375 345); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000242d00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000042a520>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 0}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource